# SQLite does not store all data

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

What I am trying to do is that when I send notifications (using Firebase) to my Android App, I store the notification message in SQLite table to let the user review his notifications in a ListView.

The problem is that SQLite store the notification text only when the App is on foreground, otherwise the phone receives the notification, but doesn't save it.

My database creation in class named : DBController

```
public DBContoller(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, "cloudmessaging.db", factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Messages(MSG TEXT,created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Messages");
}
ContentValues cv;
//add
public void add(String MSG){
    cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("MSG",MSG);
    this.getWritableDatabase().insertOrThrow("Messages", "", cv);
}
public void selectAll(List lst){
    Cursor cursor= this.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Messages order by created_at DESC ",null);
    lst.clear();
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        lst.add("Message : "+cursor.getString(0)+" - ["+cursor.getString(1)+" ]");
    }
}
```

How I store Notification Messages:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notifBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Gi2017 :)")
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(notifsound)
            .setContentIntent(pendingintent);

    NotificationManager notifManager=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notifManager.notify(0/*notification ID*/,notifBuilder.build());

    try{
        DBContoller db=new DBContoller(getApplicationContext(),"",null,1);
        db.add(body);
    }catch(Exception e){Log.d("error DB",e.getMessage());}
```

How I show stored Messages:

```
DBContoller db;
ListView lstAfficher;
db=new DBContoller(getApplicationContext(),"",null,1);
    lstAfficher = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
    db.selectAll(lst);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.listlayout,lst);
    lstAfficher.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Are you seeing any logcat messages that say "error DB"?

Comment: Can you post a sample payload that you're sending? :)

Comment: @Karakuri no errors

Comment: @AL. what do you mean like JSON file ? im using FireBase IDE to send notifications i fill up message and data(key,message)

Comment: Your code looks okay.  Add some `Log` statements to `DBContoller`.  In particular, `insertOrThrow()` returns the row ID or -1 if error.  Add a `Log` statement to show the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely sending notification messages. As the [documentation for Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) says, notifications messages are handled by the system when you're app is backgrounded:

> Use notification messages when you want FCM to handle displaying a notification on your client app's behalf. Use data messages when you want to process the messages on your client app.

If you always want your app code to get the message, you should be sending a [data message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages).

Comment: hey thanks for your support, tried working with data, notification arrives successfully even if app killed or in background but data (in method onMessageReceived()) got stored only when app is on Screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can create table like this.


final String NOTIFICATION_SAVE = "CREATE TABLE " + NOTIFICATION_GROUPING + "(" + ROW_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL UNIQUE," + FEED_ID + " TEXT," + MESSAGE + " TEXT," + ACTION + " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(NOTIFICATION_SAVE);


    And store data into created table like this.

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(FEED_ID , "102");
        cv.put(MESSAGE, "notification");
        db.insert(NOTIFICATION_GROUPING, null, cv);
        db.close();
```